# Store regression result in MySQL from R with RMySQL package

Tags: php, r, linear-regression, lm, rmysql

I am new to R and stuck with one problem. I will explain it by an example.

I am using R with php. I have one R script that calculates the linear regression:

```
reg_result <- lm( Y ~ A1 + A2 + A3, data=query_result)
```

And I am using the regression result `reg_result` for `prediction` like:

```
predict(reg_result, another_dataframe, interval="predict", level = 0.20)
```

It works very fine.

But my problem is that I need to use `predict` with `reg_result` in some time intervals, let say each 1 hour.

So is there any ways that I can persist the result of regression `reg_result` to use it later.

I have used RMySQL, but I dont know how to store the result of regression in mysql.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

And I can provide more details if required.

**EDIT:** Is it possible to store the R object in `MySQL blob` with RMySQL ? As I have googled and found `Currently there are no facilities to import/export BLOBs. in RMySQL`

Comment: Using coefficients is the way to go, but you could also save the results to a file (Rdata) and load the object when you need to predict at a latter time.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik It seems the best option and I applied the same, I have stored the result in one binary file and loaded when required. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: That only works if you are working alone. If you need to share the fitted objects and many other objects with a whole team of analysts you need a server somewhere. I need to put it in a MySQL database so the RData fix does not cut it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did (using RODBC, but that is a minor detail) is extract the regression coefficients from the lm object, something like this (for y~x):

```
intercept = lm$coefficients[["(Intercept)"]]
slope = lm$coefficients[["x"]])
```

Then store these coefficients in a database table, and later just use a linear function with the values from the table to predict, instead of the predict method (like `f <- function(x) { intercept + slope*x }`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer ROLO, I will try to solve the issue with the same method you shown.

Answer (score 2):

The solution provided by ROLO is very fine and working same as I required.

But I have gone with other way to make it less complex.

1) Stored the result in binary file

```
reg_result <- lm( Y ~ A1 + A2 + A3, data=query_result)
saveRDS(reg_result,"example.dat");
```

2) And loaded when required

```
reg_result <- readRDS("example.dat", refhook = NULL);
predict(reg_result, another_dataframe, interval="predict", level = 0.20)
```

Hope it will help someone else on how to store the regression result in binary files and retrieve when required.